# Selecting fixed number of results through Django get_object_or_404

Tags: python, django-views

Through normal python, in views.py in Django, my code is:

```
latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

(Question is the name of my model)
I need to order my results as well as display only 5 results.
How do i do the same thing with get_object_or_404 function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_list_or_404` with your current Queryset, thereby wrapping the 404 logic in the function:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404

latest_question_list = get_list_or_404(Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5])
```

Comment: Thank you. This was what i was looking for